# How to get the value from class in func? Changed value does not show up in my gui

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got a code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
window = Tk()
window.title("T")
window.geometry('1000x100')
real_ans = ""
def clicked():
    real_ans = ""
    class Random:
        def __init__(self, width, height, random):
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.random = random
            random = ""
            for i in range(height):
                for a in range(width):
                    random = random + str(randint(0, 9))
                random = random + "\n"
    ans = Random(10, 10, "")
    ans = ans.random
    real_ans = ans
    print(ans)
    lbl.configure(text=real_ans)
btn = Button(window, text="Create new ID", bg="orange", fg="red", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=0, row=0)
lbl = Label(window, text="ans")
lbl.grid(column=1, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

I can't get the value of ans, it's empty but the varible random in class Random has a value!

Comment: Can you fix your indentations and describe what exactly your code should do? It is hard to help you without that

Comment: Change `random = ...` with `self.random = ...`

Answer (score 0):

You only change the local `random` after assinging it first to `self.random` - so `self.random` will never change

> ```
> def clicked():
>     real_ans = ""
>     class Random:
>         def __init__(self, width, height, random):
>             self.height = height
>             self.width = width
>             self.random = random  # assing here
>             # you ever only change random
>             # you never assign it back to the class instance
>             random = ""
>             for i in range(height):
>                 for a in range(width):
>                     random = random + str(randint(0, 9))
>             random = random + "\n" 
>
>             # you could assign back here - approach is bad overall
>             self.random = random
>
> ans = Random(10, 10, "")
> ans = ans.random
> real_ans = ans
> print(ans)
> lbl.configure(text=real_ans)
> ```

It would be better to use smarter code:

```
from random import sample

def randomIDs(amount,digits):
    # 10**4     == 1000 
    # 10**(4+1) == 10000
    # range (10**4, 10**5) ==> 1000 to 9999  your number range
    return list(map(str,
                    (sample(range(10**digits, 10**(digits+1)), k = amount))))

def clicked():
    real_ans = "\n".join(randomIDs(10,10)) 
    lbl.configure(text=real_ans)
```

to get (after click):

[image: Picture of some IDs in your tk gui]

See [random.sample(*population, k, *, counts=None*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to create a list of unique values from a population (f.e. a list or range)